# How can I fit my GARCH model to a time series in R?

Tags: r

I´m completely new to R and I´m trying to develop a gjr-Garch(1,1) to predict goverment bond yields.

So I specified the model with:

```
garch_test <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "gjrGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                         mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0)), 
                         distribution.model = "std")
```

and want to fit it to the data set by:

```
garch_test_fit <- ugarchfit(spec = garch_test, data = Obs_per_parkinson_var)
```

However I receive the error message:

> Error in .extractdata(data) :    (list) object cannot be coerced to
>   type 'double'

My data contains the date and the variance of the bonds and the class is:  `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
#If the ACF of your data shows that your data has general autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity then use the code below:
install.packages("tseries")
library(tseries)
your.garch.model <- garch(data = Obs_per_parkinson_var, order=c(1,1), grad = "numerical", trace = FALSE)
```